# why is my domain at my apache web server (windows 11) connection time out?

Tags: dns, webserver, windows-11

I've installed an apache web server to one of my windows 11 machines. I forwarded the ports 80 and 443 to this machine. I can access it by my world wide ip and machines local ip through browser but when i try with domain name it sometimes works but generally it waits a while and then connection times out.

I also added A records at my domain provider like below: (TTL = 1 hour)

[image]

Also gave permission from windows firewall for both private and local networks.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out, although i wrote plain domain name in the browser chrome was changing it to https version of the site and that was causing the error.